# Where to ask questions related to (public) transport?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to learn more about transport of passengers/goods. Especially, I'm interested in the capacity of these modes of transport. (Tons/m³ or number of passengers in an hour)....  Is there a site suited for this kind of question? I don't really know where to post it...

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such site on Stack Exchange at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps [travel.se]?

Comment: @Mithrandir "Tons/M³ or number of passengers in an hour"? I don't think it will fit there.

Comment: It _might_ be on-topic on [Engineering.SE]. However, they do **not** allow [check-my-work-questions](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335/the-engineering-se-policy-on-check-my-work-questions).

Comment: We may need a little more information about the question to answer this properly. I'm thinking about [Mechanics.SE], but I think that site is more aimed at repair and maintenance of personal vehicles. So that would NOT be a good choice.

Answer (score 6):

Consider [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) if the reason you want these numbers is to work out fuel usage per passenger per mile and the like. Such questions have been welcome there in the past. There is also an Aviation site if you want to discuss specific planes.

I would not suggest [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) unless you specifically want to take a train or bus that holds X passengers or travels Y mph.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is solely about statistics, maybe a site like Wikipedia is what you are looking for.

If your question is about the use of those means of transportation, [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) might be [on-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Travel Stack Exchange is for road warriors and seasoned travelers.. If you have a question about …
>
> - modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport

So the travelling action is quite important in determining if the question is allowed or not.